# How to receive notifications when a new user registers

Tags: user-registration, notifications

I am running a WordPress site for real estate and I cannot seem to figure out how to receive an email when a new user registers or downloads information from my site. If anyone could help me figure out how to turn these notifications on or what plugin I should use to receive these notifications that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way to get to get emails upon user registration - just needs to be added to your function.php file.

```
function registration_email_alert($user_id) {
    $message = strip_tags($_POST['user_login']). ' - ' . strip_tags($_POST['user_email']) . ' Has Registered To Your Website';
    wp_mail( 'youremail@website.com', 'New User Has Registered', $message );
}
add_action('user_register', 'registration_email_alert');
```

I'm sure there's also a way to get notified upon downloads but that might take extra time to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

To send a notification email when a user registers on your WordPress website, you can use the wp_mail() function. Here's an example of a custom function you can add to your theme's functions.php file or a custom plugin:

```
// Hook into the user registration process
add_action('user_register', 'send_notification_on_registration', 10, 1);

function send_notification_on_registration($user_id) {
// Get user data
$user_info = get_userdata($user_id);

// Set the recipient email address
$to = 'recipient@example.com';

// Set the subject for the email
$subject = 'New User Registration';

// Set the message for the email
$message = 'A new user has registered on your website.' . "\n\n";
$message .= 'Username: ' . $user_info->user_login . "\n";
$message .= 'Email: ' . $user_info->user_email . "\n";

// Additional headers
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

// Send the email
wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Replace 'recipient@example.com' with the actual email address where you want to receive the notification. This function uses the user_register action hook to trigger the email when a new user registers on your site.